# Sort two dimensional list python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a two dimensional list like this

```
a = [[42, 206], [45, 40], [45, 205], [46, 41], [46, 205], [47, 40], [47, 202], [48, 40], [48, 202], [49, 38]]
```

Actually these are coordinates in 2D-Euclidean space. I want to sort it like in a way that close points come in a sequence. So, the list looks like the following

```
sorted_a = [[45,205],[42,206],[46,205],[47,202],[48,202],[45,40],[46,41],[47,40],[48,40],[49,38]]
```

I have also used the method

```
sorted_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))
```

but it is not returning me required results. Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The closest to the origin?

Comment: What do you mean by *"sort it like in a way that **close points come in a sequence**"* ?

Comment: I mean closest to each other. Actually I want to do some kind of clusters but i do not want to run cluster analysis for this. I have a list like this and I just want to average the closest point within a given threshold which I can decide myself. But the objective is to average closes points.

Comment: @AzfarFaizan: but you cannot sort on a criterion that is defined between two elements, since that a partial ordering...

Comment: I've added tags so more knowledgeable people will see this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a sorting problem; it's more of a grouping one (or optimization?)

Sorting requires some criteria for putting the [45,205] list before [42,206].  `key` works if you can come up with one number that represents the desired order.

For example calculate the distance from the origin

`A = np.array(a)` creates a numpy array:

```
In [346]: A
Out[346]: 
array([[ 42, 206],
       [ 45,  40],
       [ 45, 205],
       [ 46,  41],
       [ 46, 205],
       [ 47,  40],
       [ 47, 202],
       [ 48,  40],
       [ 48, 202],
       [ 49,  38]])
```

distance or **radius** in polar coordinates is sum of squares (`sqrt` isn't needed for this purpose).  Applying `argsort` to this ranks the points by distance from origin.

```
In [347]: np.sum(A**2,axis=1)
Out[347]: array([44200,  3625, 44050,  3797, 44141,  3809, 43013,  3904, 43108,  3845])
In [348]: r = np.sum(A**2,axis=1)
In [349]: idx = np.argsort(r)
In [350]: idx
Out[350]: array([1, 3, 5, 9, 7, 6, 8, 2, 4, 0], dtype=int32)
In [351]: A[idx,:]
Out[351]: 
array([[ 45,  40],
       [ 46,  41],
       [ 47,  40],
       [ 49,  38],
       [ 48,  40],
       [ 47, 202],
       [ 48, 202],
       [ 45, 205],
       [ 46, 205],
       [ 42, 206]])
```

The list equivalent operation uses a key function like

```
def foo(xy):
    x,y=xy
    return x**2+y**2
In [356]: sorted(a, key=foo)
Out[356]: 
[[45, 40],
 [46, 41],
 [47, 40],
 [49, 38],
 [48, 40],
 [47, 202],
 [48, 202],
 [45, 205],
 [46, 205],
 [42, 206]]
```

## Pairwise distances

In `numpy` it's fairly easy to come up with pairwise distance (even easier with one of the `scipy` tools).  But what would you do with those?  What defines order based on such distances?

For example to use the kind of iteration that we are often asked to 'vectorize':

```
In [369]: D = np.zeros((10,10))
In [370]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     for j in range(i,10):
     ...:         D[i,j] = np.sqrt(sum((A[i,:]-A[j,:])**2))
                  # D[i,j] = np.linalg.norm(A[i,:]-A[j,:])

In [372]: D.astype(int)
Out[372]: 
array([[  0, 166,   3, 165,   4, 166,   6, 166,   7, 168],
       [  0,   0, 165,   1, 165,   2, 162,   3, 162,   4],
       [  0,   0,   0, 164,   1, 165,   3, 165,   4, 167],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 164,   1, 161,   2, 161,   4],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 165,   3, 165,   3, 167],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 162,   1, 162,   2],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 162,   1, 164],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 162,   2],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 164],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

is a matrix of distances, rounded for ease of display.

numpy has a **lexical sort**.  We could use that to sort on the 2nd coordinate first, and then the 1st coor.  That would group all those 200's together:

```
In [375]: np.lexsort(A.T)
Out[375]: array([9, 1, 5, 7, 3, 6, 8, 2, 4, 0], dtype=int32)
In [376]: A[_,:]
Out[376]: 
array([[ 49,  38],
       [ 45,  40],
       [ 47,  40],
       [ 48,  40],
       [ 46,  41],
       [ 47, 202],
       [ 48, 202],
       [ 45, 205],
       [ 46, 205],
       [ 42, 206]])
```

pairwise distances with that sorted array look like:

```
array([[  0,   4,   2,   2,   4, 164, 164, 167, 167, 168],
       [  0,   0,   2,   3,   1, 162, 162, 165, 165, 166],
       [  0,   0,   0,   1,   1, 162, 162, 165, 165, 166],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   2, 162, 162, 165, 165, 166],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 161, 161, 164, 164, 165],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   3,   3,   6],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   4,   3,   7],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   3],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   4],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

## Search over permutations

Another way of thinking of this problem is as a search problem, for example seeking to find the order of points that minimizes the 'travel' distance, i.e. the sum of distances between successive points.

With the original `a` (`A`), the distance (with default `np.linalg.norm` method) between successive points is

```
In [407]: np.linalg.norm(A[1:]-A[:-1],axis=1)
Out[407]: 
array([ 166.02710622,  165.        ,  164.00304875,  164.        ,
        165.00303028,  162.        ,  162.00308639,  162.        ,
        164.00304875])
```

and their sum:

```
In [408]: _.sum()
Out[408]: 1474.0393203904973
```

With the `lexsort` order

```
In [410]: np.linalg.norm(A1[1:]-A1[:-1],axis=1)
Out[410]: 
array([   4.47213595,    2.        ,    1.        ,    2.23606798,
        161.00310556,    1.        ,    4.24264069,    1.        ,
          4.12310563])
In [411]: _.sum()
Out[411]: 181.07705580534656
```

Clearly this has better clustering, mainly based on the 2nd column values.

Your `sorted_a` improves this sum a bit:

```
In [414]: sortedA = np.array(sorted_a)
In [415]: np.linalg.norm(sortedA[1:]-sortedA[:-1],axis=1)
Out[415]: 
array([   3.16227766,    4.12310563,    3.16227766,    1.        ,
        162.0277754 ,    1.41421356,    1.41421356,    1.        ,
          2.23606798])
In [416]: _.sum()
Out[416]: 179.53993144488973
```

A brute force solution is to try all the permutations, and pick the one that minimizes this sum.

Comment: Thanks for a brief answer